# Show a ViewController that is not in UITabBarController's viewControllers list

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a UITabBarController and i'm setting some ViewControllers to its viewControllers list like below

```
let tabBar = UITabBarController();
tabBar.viewControllers = vcs;
```

When view is loaded, the firs ViewController in `vcs` list will be shown.
What i want is, showing a UIViewController that is not in `vcs` list (and none of tabBar must be selected).
I want to show this UIViewController only when view is loaded for the first time. After that the user tapped one of the tabBarItems, i want to load the associated ViewController.
So my problem is 'Showing a UIViewController' that is not in `vcs` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)`.

Make yourself delegate of your `UITabBarController`, depending if you use Storyboard or not, it might be easier to create a custom class that inherit from `UITabBarController` be itself `delegate` and set that class into Storyboard.

```
var hasNotShownYet = false

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard hasNotShownYet else { return true /* Allow selection as "normal" */ }
    presentCustomVCModally()
    hasNotShowYet = true
    return false
}
```